# exported JSON file incorrect format

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

So I have been working on a program that takes two JSON files, puts them into two dictionaries, combines them based on a common key and then writes these a new JSON file. each record needs to be its own document inside the JSON file. i have managed to combine the two files

My attempt

```
import json


OUTFILE = 'c:\\Users\\kiero\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\source\\AmazonDataSettest.json'  # Text file with generated JSON
out_f = open(OUTFILE, 'w')

asin_with_reviews = {}
asin_with_meta_data = {}
final = {}

line_counter = 0
for line in open("c:\\Users\\kiero\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\source\\videogames.json", 'r'):
    json_line = json.loads(line)
    asin_with_meta_data[json_line["asin"]] = json_line
    if line_counter % 10000 == 0:
        print(line_counter)
    line_counter += 1

line_counter = 0
for line in open("c:\\Users\\kiero\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\source\\reviewstest.json", 'r'):
    json_line = json.loads(line)
    asin = json_line["asin"]
    if asin in asin_with_reviews:
        contained_reviews = asin_with_reviews[asin]
        contained_reviews.append(json_line)
        asin_with_reviews[asin] = contained_reviews
    else:
        new_reviews = []
        new_reviews.append(json_line)
        asin_with_reviews[asin] = new_reviews

    if line_counter % 10000 == 0:
        print(line_counter)
    line_counter += 1
line_counter = 0

for key in (asin_with_meta_data.keys() | asin_with_reviews.keys()):
    if key in asin_with_meta_data: final.setdefault(key, []).append(asin_with_meta_data[key])
    if key in asin_with_reviews: final.setdefault(key, []).append(asin_with_reviews[key])
    if line_counter % 10000 == 0:
        print(line_counter)
        line_counter += 1
print("final dict merged")

list(final.keys())
with open("c:\\Users\\kiero\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\source\\AmazonDataSettest.json", "w") as json_file:
    for key in final.items():
        print(json.dumps(key), file=json_file)
```

now it writes each JSON object to its own line, however, it is not doing it in the correct format. I am getting it in this format

```
[  
   "B000CSR2WE",
   [  
      {  
         "asin":"B000CSR2WE",
         "description":"Sega CD game",
         "price":199.99,
         "imUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/212FW43G1JL.jpg",
         "related":{  
            "also_bought":[  
               "B0007WC7ES",
               "B000A7DZ9Q",
               "B00002ST6Y",
               "B0007UF2DI",
               "B000035XN5",
               "B000K5ZW1C",
               "B000VMMXTI",
               "B000GO5BOK"
            ],
            "buy_after_viewing":[  
               "B0009OGJ02"
            ]
         },
         "salesRank":{  
            "Video Games":38713
         },
         "categories":[  
            [  
               "Video Games",
               "Kids & Family"
            ],
            [  
               "Video Games",
               "More Systems",
               "Sega CD",
               "Games"
            ]
         ],
         [  
            {  
               "reviewerID":"A1G0VFQ9198IUF",
               "asin":"B00000DMAU",
               "reviewerName":"al",
               "helpful":[  
                  1,
                  1
               ],
               "reviewText":"........",
               "overall":5.0,
               "summary":"the first true race game",
               "unixReviewTime":1339372800,
               "reviewTime":"06 11, 2012"
            },
            {  
               "reviewerID":"ACSZTM3KHFPBL",
               "asin":"B00000DMAU",
               "reviewerName":"Andy Griffith \"Bloodrayne\"",
               "helpful":[  
                  0,
                  0
               ],
               "reviewText":"This is, by far, undeniably the",
               "overall":5.0,
               "summary":"....",
               "unixReviewTime":1339372800,
               "reviewTime":"06 11, 2012"
            }
         }
      ]
   ]
```

when I need it to be in this format:

```
{  
   "asin":"B000CSR2WE",
   "description":"Sega CD game",
   "price":199.99,
   "imUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/212FW43G1JL.jpg",
   "related":{  
      "also_bought":[  
         "B0007WC7ES",
         "B000A7DZ9Q",
         "B00002ST6Y",
         "B0007UF2DI",
         "B000035XN5",
         "B000K5ZW1C",
         "B000VMMXTI",
         "B000GO5BOK"
      ],
      "buy_after_viewing":[  
         "B0009OGJ02"
      ]
   },
   "salesRank":{  
      "Video Games":38713
   },
   "categories":[  
      [  
         "Video Games",
         "Kids & Family"
      ],
      [  
         "Video Games",
         "More Systems",
         "Sega CD",
         "Games",
         [  
            {  
               "reviewerID":"A1G0VFQ9198IUF",
               "asin":"B00000DMAU",
               "reviewerName":"al",
               "helpful":[  
                  1,
                  1
               ],
               "reviewText":"........",
               "overall":5.0,
               "summary":"the first true race game",
               "unixReviewTime":1339372800,
               "reviewTime":"06 11, 2012"
            },
            {  
               "reviewerID":"ACSZTM3KHFPBL",
               "asin":"B00000DMAU",
               "reviewerName":"Andy Griffith \"Bloodrayne\"",
               "helpful":[  
                  0,
                  0
               ],
               "reviewText":"This is, by far, undeniably the",
               "overall":5.0,
               "summary":"....",
               "unixReviewTime":1339372800,
               "reviewTime":"06 11, 2012"
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
```

Comment: `json.dumps(key[1][0])`

Comment: while that is sorting the format issue out. now they two json files are not combining